# Consume Java CXF WS exposed over SOAP from ServiceStack client

Tags: web-services, cxf, servicestack

**Context:**
I'd like to use ServiceStack to build a SOAP client in order to consume an existing Java CXF WebService, exposed over SOAP with defined WSDL (I have no control over the WS itself). I may need to add a couple of extra headers the SOAP envelope for authorization purposes.

**Question:**
Would all of the above be possible, and if so, what are the gotchas? If there are any specific examples, links would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the other way round of having other clients consuming [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) web services would make more sense.

Using ServiceStack to consume other clients is not an ideal strategy. ServiceStack server and client supports a coarse-grained, DTO-first approach, it wouldn't handle variations in this theme that other frameworks spit out.

Comment: you did provide a good "best practices" answer, which guides me in the right direction. While this doesn't resolve my current problem (obviously, the DTOs coming back from CXF's WSDL aren't Service Stack's DTOs, therefore I can't use them to generate Servie Stack proxies), but it does help understand the philosophy of the project. I'll probably have more questions now :)